# System.DmlException: Insert failed. DUPLICATES_DETECTED Automatic email help

Tags: apex, error, duplicate-management

***Apex Class***

```
global class EmailToLeadCanford implements 

Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

  /**
   * Handling Inbound Email
   * @param   Messaging.InboundEmail      Email object
   * @param   Messaging.InboundEnvelope   Email enveloppe
   * @return  Messaging.InboundEmailResult
   * @access  global
   */
  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

    Lead lead = new Lead();
     CampaignMember cm = new CampaignMember();
    lead.FirstName = email.fromname.substring(0, email.fromname.indexOf(' '));
    lead.LastName = email.fromname.substring(email.fromname.indexOf(' '));
    lead.Email = envelope.fromAddress;
    lead.Description = email.plainTextBody;
    String textBody = email.plainTextBody;
    String companyName;
    Integer startPos = textBody.indexOf('CompanyName:');
    if (textBody.indexOf('CompanyName:') > -1) {
      Integer endPos = textBody.indexOf('.', textBody.indexOf('CompanyName:'));
      companyName = textBody.substring(startPos + 'CompanyName:'.length(), endPos);
    }
    lead.Company = companyName != NULL ? companyName : '(not provided)';
    lead.LeadSource = 'Rightmove';
    lead.Status = 'New';
    cm.LeadId = lead.Id;
    cm.CampaignId = '701g0000000aKV0';
    insert lead;
    insert cm;



    LeadService.executeAssignmentAsync(new Set<Id>{lead.Id});

    return result;

  }

}
```

***Full Error***

> This message was created automatically by the mail system.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
>
> canfordcliffs@242t8fojjobtrnxkss553w86f21rmvrimofn7q2b82l87qgajt.g-6stk2eak.cs17.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com (Undelivered): 554 The apex class EmailToLeadCanford failed due to: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, You're creating a duplicate record. We recommend you use an existing record instead.: []

Comment: do i need to upsert the CM rather than insert?

Comment: Yes, change it to an upsert for both the lead and campaign member.

Comment: as an aside, you should be querying for the Campaign, not hardcoding the ID - where the Campaign name is saved in a config param - such as in a custom metadata type or custom setting. Campaign IDs won't necessarily be the same between sandbox and prod